# spring boot project not hot reloaded when code has been updated, using mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm learning java spring boot, and wonder can hot reload still work if using `mvn spring-boot:run` to start the application. If does, how to make it works?

Have tried to update and save the .java file, however application not restarted automatically.

initialized and run the application through:

```
spring init --build=maven -java-version=1.8 --dependencies=web ^
  --group-id=com.foo --artifact-id=myspringboot --packaging=jar myspringboot

cd myspringboot 

mvn spring-boot:run
```

OS: windows 10, IDE: notepad, JDK: 1.8

spring-boot-maven-plugin already included in pom.xml according to [Using Boot Devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

Comment: Any specific reason why you prefer the notepad and not an IDE like VS code. Which does the job for you. The IDE listens for the on save files, recompiles and run functionalities which makes it happen.

Comment: When learning new topics, prefer not using IDE first hoping to get more understanding on how things works. Have tried on clean VS Code too, still no luck.

Comment: Yes..."reloading" works normally for/from "target/..." folder (not src)...you (or another build process;) have to modify something there..

Comment: (e.g. `mvn package -DskipTests` from another shell;)

Comment: @xerx593 wow, thanks for the direction, rebuild by `mvn package` did work!

Comment: IDE's do it normally "on the fly"... while typing/saving